# Cannot share List value between threads using volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, webserver

The server is initialized then thread started. The thread writes to `List<String> JSON_LIST`. When http request comes to parent thread it shows that `JSON_LIST` is empty however other thread have already added new element. Why volatile is not working?

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

public class HelloWorld extends Thread {
            @GET
            @Produces("text/plain")
            public String getClichedMessage() {
                // Return some cliched textual content
                return JSON_LIST.get(JSON_LIST.size() - 1);
            }
            private volatile List<String> JSON_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

            public void addJSONRecord(String s){
                 JSON_LIST.add(s);
            }
         @Override
            public void run() {
                 addJSONRecord(json);
        }

         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/");
    server.start();
    (new HelloWorld()).start();

    System.out.println("Server running");
    System.out.println("Visit: http://localhost:8080/service");
    System.out.println("Hit return to stop...");
    System.in.read();
    System.out.println("Stopping server");
    server.stop(0);
    System.out.println("Server stopped");
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I have one class. It should acts as web server. Additional theread was created to populate JSON_LIST with records. The problem is when I try to `return JSON_LIST.get(JSON_LIST.size() - 1)` it always returns ArrayindexOutOfBound exception. Therefore, Jersey thread cannot see updates made to `private volatile List<String> JSON_LIST`.

How to fix it?

**UPDATE2:**

I have tried several things:

`private volatile CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> JSON_LIST = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();`

and

```
public String getClichedMessage() {
            synchronized (JSON_LIST){
            return JSON_LIST.get(JSON_LIST.size() - 1);
            }

    }
    public void addJSONRecord(String s){
        synchronized (JSON_LIST){ 
            JSON_LIST.add(s);
        }
    }
```

**Nothing solved the problem**

Comment: I very much doubt your `HelloWorld` thread is also a handler within Jersey. Just because you annotated its method with `@GET` doesn't make it a handler. Please show us what you are actually doing.

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example. I don't know what you are trying to demonstrate with the code you've posted. I don't think your issue is with `volatile` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because volatile only guarantees the visibility of a new value of JSON_LIST. I.e., it guarantees that, if you assign a new list to the JSON_LIST variable in thread A, thread B will see the new value of the variable.

Changes to the list referenced by the variable are not made thread-safe by volatile. You need a thread-safe list to have such a guarantee, or you need to synchronize every access to the list.

EDIT:

reading your code again, this seems more than a concurrency problem. Jersey doesn't use the same HelloWorld instance than the one you explicitely create and start in your main method. So your main method adds in a list, and Jersey reads in another one.

Comment: Can you give example? I cannot put `synchronized` in `addJSONRecord` method signature, neither can I wrap `JSON_LIST.add(s)` with `synchronized`

Comment: I need the easiest solution.

Comment: As I said: use a thread-safe list implementation (like CopyOnWriteArrayList), or always access the list from a synchronized block (all blocks being synchronized on the same lock). This is concurrency nuts and bolts. You should learn it instead of expecting code to copy and paste without understanding: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html